# android BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null when jpeg is saved with Microsoft Paint

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I have some jpeg file stored into application private storage. I'm showing them in an ImageView and everything works properly.

But for some jpeg, with sizes similar to the others, BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null.

This happens with all jpegs generated by Microsoft Paint: just by taking a jpeg that works well, loading into msPaint and saving it unmodified, to get a not working jpeg.

This is the code (the filepath and filename are properly set because it works for many files):

```
...
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ...
    private ImageView myImage;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        File f=new File(basedir, list.get(imageIndex).getFile());
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());
        if (b != null){
            myImage.setImageBitmap(b);
        } else {
            myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default);
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I've also tried FileInputStream, as suggested somewhere else but with the same result:

```
...
File f=new File(basedir, list.get(imageIndex).getFile());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
if (b != null){
    myImage.setImageBitmap(b);
} else {
    myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default);
}
...
```

Does BitmapFactory have any known limitation? Is there any way to check jpeg characteristics??

Comment: And if you start with a much smaller jpg?

Comment: I tried down to something like an icon (50x50px) with the same result.